# ¿Como puedo poner texto en una tabla debajo de otro texto?

Tags: html, css

tengo una duda y es que como puedo poner en una tabla un titulo en una celda y justo debajo del titulo poner texto os paso captura:https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xMwD.jpg

```
 <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <td><br>HTML</br></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Versión a usar</td>   
              <td>Jackson</td>              
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

A través de etiquetas HTML puede ser la manera mas sencilla de maquetar lo que deseas, es decir tienes una tabla con un encabezado similar a este:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Encabezado Uno
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Si ahora deseas aplicarle un texto que quede justo debajo de donde dice: *Encabezado Uno*, puedes insertar un párrafo a través del uso de `p` el cual al tener una naturaleza de bloque ocupará todo el ancho disponible moviendose a una siguiente línea.

Así:

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Encabezado Uno
        <p>coloca algo a detalle aquí</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

La ventaja de lo anterior es que:

- Al momento sin involucrar CSS consigues el resultado deseado
- Si necesitas estilizar por medio de CSS ese texto, lo podrás recuperar fácilmente pues esta dentro de una etiqueta a la cual le puedes asignar:

  - una clase
  - o un id

Y la salida sería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Html</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Es un lenguaje...</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Sí necesitas varias columnas...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Html</td>
    <td>Otra columna</td>
    <td>Otra columna</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Es un lenguaje...</td>
    <td>otro texto</td>
    <td>otro texto</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Luego le das con css o bootstrap la apariencia y espaciado.

Si quieres que esté en el mismo td

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
       <td>HTML
       </br>
        Es un lenguaje...
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```